# Подгрузка контента при прокрутке страницы (как в соцсетях)

Tags: прокрутка, контент

Имеется блог в виде длинной страницы (70 div блоков с контентом "фото+текст") 
Нужно чтобы при заходе на сайт отображались первые 3-4 поста и далее по ходу прокрутки страницы автоматически подгружались остальные. Пример можно посмотреть в соцсетях вк/ок/fb/insta. Как это реализовать? Желательно на чистом PHP и JavaScript, без использования базы данных.

Answer (score 3):

1. Создаете для ленты обработчик события `onscroll`
2. В этом обработчике смотрите какой сейчас блок показывается
3. Если последний (а лучше - предпоследний), то отправляете на сервер AJAX запрос с запросом следующей партии блоков
4. Когда пришел ответ - добавляете блоки на страницу

Comment: А есть готовый пример?: